# Twitter : How to upload video of dropbox tp twitter?

Tags: video, twitter, upload

I have to upload video in dropbox to twitter.
I used scottybo/twitter for it
this package uploads images successfully but didn't upload dropbox videos.

```
$uploadedMedia = Twitter::uploadMedia([
        'media_type'=>'video/*',
        'media' => file_get_contents('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3gi43cvzx3axg4k/Shot%20by%20Shintaro%20Shimada_ea754591-de67-4308-891c-07d89b97bff2.mp4?dl=0')
      ]);
```

this code shows 400 error
Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

video uploading should be processed by chunking

```
$buffer = file_get_contents($url);
$response = Twitter::post('media/upload', ['command' => 'INIT', 'media_type' => 'video/mp4', 'total_bytes' => strlen($buffer)], true);
$media_id = $response->media_id;
$response = Twitter::post('media/upload', ['command' => 'APPEND', 'media_id' => $media_id, 'segment_index' => '0', 'media' => $buffer], true);
$uploadedMedia = Twitter::post('media/upload', ['command' => 'FINALIZE', 'media_id' => $media_id], true);
```